# API error when connecting to klick-tipp "API Zugriff verweigert" (Access Denied)

Tags: php

I want to connect to the Klick-tip Api and get contacts for syncing with another application.

I have the right password and Username to the API and it logs in and even creates a session key in postman however when I try to run any of the other gets and posts it says access denied. I am using the code samples that they provide and downloaded the helper [file](https://www.klick-tipp.com/de/content_includes/apidoc/phpconnector.zip") that I include.

```
/**
 * Get all active subscribers. Login required.
 *
 * @return array [subscriber_id]
 * Use subscriber_get to get subscriber details.
 */

require_once('klicktipp.api.inc');

$username = 'username'; // Replace with username
$password = 'password'; // Replace with password

$connector = new KlicktippConnector();
$logged_in = $connector->login($username, $password);
$subscriber_ids = $connector->subscriber_index();
$connector->logout();

if ($logged_in) {
    print '<br> Login successful. <br>';
} else {
    print $connector-> get_last_error();
}


if ($subscriber_ids) {
    print('<pre>'.print_r($subscriber_ids, true).'</pre>');
} else {
    print $connector->get_last_error();
}
```

I expect to get an array with the subscriber ids. But i just get the following output from that code. Login successful. then

````
Subscriber index failed: : API Zugriff verweigert. ```
````

Comment: It looks like the account you are using for the communication with the API does not have permission to call those forbidden API methods. You should check the settings for that account.

Comment: I think it is the issue I have but I don't know for sure because nothing is said about this in their documentation. so I was just looking almost everywhere and I thought maybe someone has faced the same and could direct me. i dont see any other reason as to why this would fail. But let me look further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, maybe this will be of help to someone when they get the same problem. After doing a lot of playing around with the account that I have. I managed to get why it was not working. For some reason, Klick-tipp dashboard says I can select a user as an administrator with the access type as "**All Access**" and yet the user doesn't have access to the API! I am not sure why they put it like that because it is very misleading.

Anyway to answer the question I had to create a new subaccount and give it access type "**API Only**". Apparently only such accounts are allowed to use the API commands (from what I have experienced). And with that, I was able to get the data I wanted.